# Preventing excel from altering cell contents to take literal values

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I have scripted out a module that reads data I paste in from a SQL dump, and converts it into a data insert script to SQL. It is working great, only problem is for cells that contain items like:

11-20

instead of filling my value as '11-20', it is converting it to '20-Nov'.

I have adjusted how i read the cell from text to value to value2, Text comes the closest to right (rest do a math calc that tosses my overall sheet off even worse, namely dates). I have also tried such things as a `Range("X:X").clear` and `clearformat` as well. This also does not do the trick.

How do I force my string read of this cell to be the literal CSV content, and ignore the formula/calculations that excel is tossing at me?

EDIT:
Thanks to BraX for the solution!

I was unable to accomplish this by copying from one tab to the next within Excel, but i did get it to work by pausing my operation with a message box prompting the user to simply navigate to SQL and put the contents of the data in to the clip board. This works perfectly now!

```
Cells.Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

    MsgBox "Please navigate to SQL and copy your data to be insurted, including headers. When done click OK"
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before** adding the data to the sheet, set the `NumberFormat` to `@` for the affected columns.

Example:

```
ActiveWorkBook.WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"
```

That will format the values to `Text` and prevent them from being interpreted as a `Date` when the data is added. Once Excel decides it's a date, it's too late.

Comment: Bingo! This did the trick! Thank you for your reply! I did not think about adjusting the format before pasting in the data...

Answer (score 0):

i am pretty sure all it takes is to format the cells, right click on the range of cells you want formatted as plain text, click "FORMAT CELLS" and under the "NUMBER TAB" it shows the "CATEGORY" of the type of formatting, e.g: "General, Number, Currency, etc" select where it says "Text" and click ok, any text will be evaluated the same way you write it, so even if you write "11-5-18" it will be just that and won't be considered a date or anything.

Comment: If you pre format the source file where he is pulling the data from, it will work, otherwise Excel will keep formatting as it wishes...

Comment: True, but that was not the question.

Comment: I would accept any that work, though i tried this already. This converts 11-20 to 43424. Text formatting does not work unfortunately.